# Is an object's object_id guaranteed to be unique and unchanged for the life of the object?

Tags: crystal-lang

The [crystal API docs](https://crystal-lang.org/api/master/Reference.html#object_id%3AUInt64-instance-method) say that the `object_id` is the "memory address of this object". Is that guaranteed to always be unique and the same value for the life of the object? Will Crystal ever change the memory location of an object before it is garbage collected?

Comment: Right now it's true, in the future we don't know (a moving GC might break this assumption)

Comment: @asterite Do you think `hash` will remain the same for the life of the object in the future?

Comment: Hash cannot be declared as always same because objects aren't immutable in Crystal.

Answer (score 1):

To summarize the comments by [asterite](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4990850/asterite) and [Akzhan Abdulin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1336858/akzhan-abdulin):

Currently (as of March 2017), yes. But that may not be true for all time. Hashes are no exception to this.